# Как запустить python-script при помощи php в OpenServer на локале?

Tags: php, python, openserver, exec

У меня стоит задача на сайте, который работает на PHP, сделать многопоточный запрос на другой сайт чтобы спарсить и обработать некоторые данные.
На хостинге команда ниже отлично работает и выводит данные. А на локальном сервере python не хочет запускаться вообще.

```
$cmd = 'python ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/ping-test.py';
$python =  exec($cmd, $out, $code);
```

Как можно настроить работу данной команды в openserver?
exec, сама по себе, работает.
В apache config добавлял работу с расширением py.
Хотя проблема заключается больше в самом запуске python. Пробавл проверить версию python, она не работала...

```
python --version
```

Comment: Ну так установите этот самый Python на локальный компьютер, а что еще?

Comment: Python установлен на локальный компьютер и сам по себе стабильно работает

Comment: Ну так вы не указывали, что он установлен. Если бы указали, то тогда понятное дело, что в path проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто, надо было в настройках переменной Path указать "Свой Path + Win Path".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]